# How to get the content-type of a file

Tags: c++, html, unix

I am implementing a HTTP/1.0 server that processes `GET` or `HEAD` request.

I've finished `Date`, `Last-Modified`, and `Content-Length`, but I don't know how to get the `Content-Type` of a file.

It has to return directory for directory(which I can do using `stat()` function), and for a regular file, `text/html` for `text` or `html` file, and `image/gif` for image or `gif` file.

Should this be hard-coded, using the name of the file?

I wonder if there is any function to get this `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either look at the file extension (which is what most web servers do -- see e.g. the `/etc/mime.types` file; or you could use `libmagic` to automatically determine the content type by looking at the first few bytes of the file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how sophisticated you want to be.

If the files in question are all properly named and there are only several types to handle, having a switch based file suffix is sufficient. Going to the extreme case, making the right decision no matter what the file is would probably require either duplicating the functionality of Unix `file` command or running it on file in question (and then translating the output to the proper `Content-Type`).